# 'Music Background' - does it require any article in this case?

Tags: sentence-construction, articles

Which one is the correct choice?

> "I prefer to send the video with a music background" or 
> "I prefer to send the video with music background"

I wonder whether 'music background' takes an article.

Comment: Details please! describe the issue that you have and what research you have done. Also, try to make a more descriptive question title.

Comment: I'd go for: I prefer to send the video with music in background.

Answer (score 4):

The Oxford Learners dictionary ([sense 3](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/background?q=background)) states that when we talk about **music background** then the noun **background** is **countable** and usually singular.

With singular countable nouns we use the **indefinite article** **= a**

The fact that the word *background* is preceded by *music* is not important except that music acts as a modifier (adjunct) to say what kind of background it is.

I therefore believe that this sentence is correct:

> I prefer to send the video with **a** music background.

Comment: I think this is a good explanation, but I can also see why a learner might have had a hard time figuring out if _music background_ would be treated as countable or uncountable.